# Aurigma image upload error - Package error occured: error code = 0x00000000 (Fine in Chrome not in IE 8)

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, aurigma

When running the Aurigma Image Upload control in debug mode I get the following error:

```
Package error occured: error code = 0x00000000
```

Has anyone else had this issue or know what it means in more detail?

I notice my custom package values don't all get posted even though they are set correctly on the client side.

I add values like this:

```
uploader.metadata().addCustomField('Comments', $('#Comments').val(), false);
```

My upload size per request is only about 300kb so shouldn't be an issue.

Anyone had similar issues? It works perfectly in chrome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was occurring because with the ActiveX version which works with IE only, there is a limit of 100 custom meta data items per request.

This causes the loss of some of the data causing the error.

Hope this helps someone.

They are increasing this limit with the next version too. Until then you can use there file tag feature which allows you to bundle up related sets of meta.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are two Image Uploader controls: one of them is ActiveX which works with IE only and another is Java applet which works with all other browsers. They have different codebases and work slightly different in some cases.

In debug mode you should get information about HTTP response from server. If there is no info, you can check [Error event](http://www.aurigma.com/docs/iu7/E_Uploader_Error.htm) in order to see response code and error page if they are exist.

Also you can try to debug your upload sessions with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It can give some useful information.

If nothing helps – post your problem to [Aurigma forum](http://forums.aurigma.com/yaf_topics5_Image-Uploader.aspx) or create [support case](http://www.aurigma.com/MyAurigma/CreateCase.aspx).

Comment: In debug mode I get the message I posted above. I haven't tried fiddler I will have a look. I created a support case yesterday but haven't had any response yet.

Comment: If you have “http response 500” in your console that means there was some server-side error. In most cases server gives html page with detailed error explanation. This page can be obtained via Error event as ‘errorPage’ argument(the link above). Or you can try to get it with fiddler.

Comment: it is a server 500 error and I'm running visual studio in debug mode so i can see the error being caused with my code but it is because the packagefields collection only contains data for the first 13 images and im referencing something at the 14th position. There should be 20 sets of meta but it seems to only show the first few